# Can't receive email notification of these sites after setting to 3 hours

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, email-notification

For nearly several months, I can't receive any notification about these sites, but I had set it to notice me after 3 hours:

[image]

Where can I fix this problem?

Comment: Which Stack Exchange sites? Or only *[TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)*?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum I just found in Tex-LaTeX, but it has been a long time that I haven't post question on other sites.

Comment: Are you checking your inbox within 3 hours of receiving an inbox notification on site?

Comment: @V2Blast Now, I haven't received any notification in my Email of your response here, which is far over 3 hours.

Comment: I also didn't receive any notification since August 2nd, I have it set to Daily, and I rarely mark any item as read, i.e. leaving them all "unread" which should trigger the email notification. Looks like something is broken on SE side. /cc @V2Blast (until that date, it appeared to work fine)

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard  How to leave them all "unread"?

Comment: @Y.zeng by not clicking on them. Inbox got a major change a while ago, that when opening the inbox to see the messages, all messages are still marked "unread", only clicking on message or the icon on its top right will mark it as read.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard So, now, this way not work?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking in the comment, sorry. What way is not working?

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Sorry. I can't find the option of "mark as unread" now. How can I make that choice appear?

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard: Thanks, I believe the devs have confirmed and identified the possible cause of this bug (at least a recent iteration of it), so hopefully it can be resolved soon. (I'm not sure if it's the same thing that Y. zeng has been experiencing for months, though.)

Comment: @V2Blast yeah that's surely "my" case, dates match, hopefully OP case will also be somehow solved.

Comment: @Y.zeng the unread items have a closed envelope on their top right corner, once read, the icon changes to an open envelope, and the item get a different background. There is no way to mark all items as unread again, only one by one, by clicking the open envelope. I'm not sure about the email notification, even opening a single item once might abort sending it, this is something that need further testing and might be also broken, or not behaving as expected. (i.e. notification should be sent if you have unread items in the last three hours.)

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard So, there is no way to resolve this problem unless devs do? Am I right?

Comment: @V2Blast It should be the same thing. Hope tomorrow this problem is resolved.

Comment: @Y.zeng yes, that's pretty much the case with all bugs reported here. (Otherwise it won't be a bug.)

Answer (score 8):

We've discovered that the scheduled job that batches and sends the inbox notification emails has been failing since Aug 3rd.  A fix is in the works and should be deployed tomorrow, barring any issues found during code review.

**Update (Aug 24):** The fix has been deployed and the email queue has been cleared.  If you had unread Inbox items, you should have received the email.

Comment: Would/should there be something to monitor failures like this?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek with all the monitors they already have in place, doubt there's a room to squeeze a needle, not to mention *another monitor*. :/

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yes, we're also working on improving our alerting for this type of failure.

Comment: Updated -- the fix has been deployed and executed, so emails should be flowing again.